# What tense is "He would never see her again"?

Tags: tenses, modal-verbs, backshifting, inflectional-morphology, will-be-going

In the following passage, what tense is the second sentence?

> John said goodbye to his mother. He would never see her again.

I know it's not the past tense, which would be "He never saw her again."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use of 'would' in place of the past simple](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/203458/use-of-would-in-place-of-the-past-simple) - "would" is a modal verb expressing futurity from the point of view of the past.

Comment: The past of *see* is *saw*. The past of *say* is *said*. What verb do you think *would* is an inflection of, and why?

Comment: @StuartF Time reference, tense and constructions are different things. The linked to question answers the first, not the second. It's the second, or possibly third, which the OP is asking about. Not the first, though :)

Comment: Related and possible duplicates: [1](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/132237), [2](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/114103), [3](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/229928), [4](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/298808), [5](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/366280), [6](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/423676), [7](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/476123), [8](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/546994), [9](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/561708).

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.  Reopened, with some cross-question references and retagging provided.

Answer (score 6):

Back "translation" to the (historical) present tense:
John *says* goodbye to his mother.
He *will* never see her again.

Ah, but we want the *past tense*. So, we write:

John *said* goodbye to his mother. He **would** never see her again.

***Here***, the past tense of *will* is *would*.

[MacMillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/would#:%7E:text=Would%20has%20no%20tenses%2C%20no,she%20did%20not%20buy%20it)

> In some cases would can be used as the past tense of will, for
> example, in indirect speech introduced by a verb in the past tense: I
> promised that I would visit her the next day.

That is the past tense of: He promises that he will visit her one day.

Some linguists like to just call this particular usage a modal. I don't.

Comment: _Would_ is a modal auxiliary verb, like _will, can, could, shall, should, may, might, must,_ and sometimes _need_ and _dare_. They have their own very irregular syntax and meanings. Calling some of  them "past tense" is historically accurate, but the usage died away except for idioms long ago, and modals don't otherwise inflect for tense, and rarely have any tenselike meanings, so I'm one of the linguists who don't call some, but not other, uses of _would_ "past tense".

Comment: Sometimes in English, the word *modal* refers to the concrete class of inflectionally defective English auxiliary verbs lacking both present and past participles as well as inflections by person and number. A more abstract sense refers to the modal duality of certain verbs and related periphrastic verbal expressions in which either the epistemic modality of factual necessity, probability, possibility &c (*That would be the milkman*) or the deontic modality of permission, obligation, recommendation, prohibition &c (*Would you please shut the door?*) applies.

Comment: So just what *modal* “means” in a given context depends on whether one is talking about the syntax and morphology or about the semantics and meaning.  These two overlap when we notice, for example, that modal verbs cannot be used for imperative statements, the kind with an implied *you* for their subjects like *Do be quiet* or *Go see your mother*. That's because imperatives require an infinitive inflection but modal verbs are also defective in that they lack infinitives.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes would is a modal and sometimes it is past tense. I said I would go [if he went, too]=conditional. I said I would go [past of: I say I will go]. Those are different and that's all I'm saying. Not covering every case "in the book". I wonder why you feel the need...

Comment: @tchrist, if you believe that your remarks about *would* are relevant to its use in the OP's example, then why don't you post them as an answer (an explain how they apply to that particular example)? If they are about some other uses of *would* and not about that one, then they do not constitute an objection to Lambie's very straightforward answer.

Comment: @jsw29 Because I don't think we should use the word "tense" to describe modal verbs at all, let alone use anything outside "present tense" and "past tense". I reject dreaming up longwinded terms for verbal constructions like "past future indefinite continuous passive tense". If that's the sort of "answer" sought here, then I am hardly the person to supply it, since I don't believe in such things.

Comment: @tchrist Sometimes you say things I simply cannot understand what you are saying. Like this: Because I don't think we should use the word "tense" to describe modal verbs at all, let alone use anything outside "present tense" and "past tense."

Comment: @tchrist, what you are saying seems to imply: '*would* in this sentence cannot  be meaningfully classified as to tense, because it is a modal, and modals have no tenses'. It is difficult to see how that does not constitute a possible answer to the question. You obviously think that it is a better answer than Lambie's. Posting it as an answer would enable those who come to this page to compare the two ways of conceptualising, and encourage them to reflect on which one is more illuminating.

Answer (score 2):

'He **would** never see her again.' refers to the past.

'Would' is the past form of 'will'.

'He **will** never see her again' refers to the future.

Direct: He said to her, 'I will never see you again'.

Indirect: He told her that he would never see her again.

Comment: I posted the same thing, basically.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, Professor Lawler argued:

> *Would* is a modal auxiliary verb, like *will, can, could, shall, should, may, might, must*, and sometimes *need* and *dare*. They have their own very irregular syntax and meanings. Calling some of them "past tense" is historically accurate, but the usage died away except for idioms long ago, and modals don't otherwise inflect for tense, and rarely have any tenselike meanings, so I'm one of the linguists who don't call some, but not other, uses of *would* "past tense".

Although the comment does not explicitly say so, it, in virtue of being posted on this page, pragmatically implicates, that the sentence that the question is about **cannot be classified as to tense**. In the comments that followed, tchrist defended an apparently stronger claim, that we should not use *tense* to describe modal verbs, such as *would*, at all.

(This is posted here as a 'community wiki' answer to make it easier for the future visitors to the page to see the full array of possible views of the matter.)

Answer (score 1):

The term **tense** is defined in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tense) as:

> a distinction of form in a verb to express distinctions of time or duration of the action or state it denotes

So, it's a verb form, not its meaning. If you disagree with this definition, you should edit your question. Assuming you don't, let's find out what tense the verb *was* and *would* are here:

> a. *I **was** wondering if you **would** agree with the definition.*

I'm sure you'll agree that the verb *was* is easily the past form of the verb *be*, despite the fact that *was* does not necessarily describe a past situation. Then, I'm sure you'll also agree that the verb *would* is easily the past form of the verb *will*, despite the fact that *would* does not necessarily describe a past situation.

Now, let's have a look at your example:

> *John **said** goodbye to his mother. He **would** never see her again.*

Now, I'm sure you'll agree that the verbs *said* and *would* are in their respective past forms, regardless of whether they describe past situations or not.

If you're one of those people who argue that *would* is not the past form of *will*, and that *would* is an entirely different verb than *will*, or that *would* is not even a verb, good luck with your question, because there's no answering your question then.

Answer (score -1):

The [progressive/continuous](https://www.grammar.com/progressive-tense) tense is formed with a 'verb chain' (verbs with auxiliary verbs, etc) and add the present participle (*-ing*).

The combination in **"He would never see her again"** using **'would never'** establishes a condition that begins now and continues into the future.
**Would** can also imply a future action like in "I *would* tap dance" because it is an auxiliary/helping verb; it modifies the action.

EDIT:
Though not utilizing a present participle, **He would never see her again** could be modified to **He would not be seeing her again** or **He is not seeing her again** as pointed out by @Mari-Lou A.
However, since *would* is a modal verb, it could be seen as either a past progressive or present progressive. That is, an event that has already started (or starting now) and continuing into the future. Though, neither tense inherently changes the cognitive association of the phrase, "He would never see her again"

Comment: Isn't "He **would not** ***be*** **seeing** her again." the progressive/continuous future in the past "tense"? OR "He would never **be seeing** her again. The PRESENT continuous would be "He **isn't seeing**…”

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

It’s the future imperfect.

Because, we are standing in the present, with John. At the time at which he is saying goodbye to his mother.  We've flown back in time, in order to do that, in this sentence. We are looking back but actually, we are with him, back then.

‘He would’ is looking forward to the future, from back then, where he 'never sees her again'.

So it's the future imperfect.